# how can i post a data object into an array in mongodb with mongoose

Tags: javascript, mongodb, object, mongoose-schema

how can i save this object into my mongodb model?
im  trying to add an object into my mongodb model into a variable the objects have the same label but diferente values.

```
students: [{"name":"mike","lastname":" park"},{"name":"miguel","lastname":" smith"},{"name":"michael","lastname":" park"}]

the json data should see like this:

[
 {id:"codeid",
  school:"mike's schools"
  students:[{"name":"mike","lastname":" park"},{"name":"miguel","lastname":" smith"}, 
  {"name":"michael","lastname":" park"}]
 }
]

the model of mongoose
const schoolSchema= new Schema({
school: String,
students:[[]] // is this the correct declaration?

})
```

Answer (score 0):

Your declare code is wrong because every use key defined in schema so before use key defined in schema.

if you want to another array schema then use following code

```
const studentDetailSchema = new Schema({
  name: String,
  lastname: String,
});
const schoolSchema = new Schema({
  school: String,
  students: [studentDetailSchema], // is this the correct declaration?
});
```

Comment: uhm, but is this new studentDetailSchema  save all data? the next time that i create a new data for schoolSchema would have the data from the new and the last schoolSchema or not?

Answer (score 0):

i made this change, and its works

```
the model of mongoose
const schoolSchema= new Schema({
school: String,
students:Object 
the  result was like this
[
 {id:"codeid",
  school:"mike's schools"
  students:[{"name":"mike","lastname":" park"},{"name":"miguel","lastname":" smith"}, 
  {"name":"michael","lastname":" park"}]
 }
]

i post in my form the array 

students: [{"name":"mike","lastname":" park"},{"name":"miguel","lastname":" smith"},{"name":"michael","lastname":" park"}]
```